# What is the function behind this graph?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on what the function behind the graph might be?
It seems to be similar to something like $a-(1/(1+e^(ln(x)-b))$ but less continuous in the end.

Note: the $x$-axis is Logarithmic scale.

Comment: What scale das the x-axis have? Where is the graph from?

Comment: It could literally be anything.

Comment: the graph is a plot of consumption behavior based on a certain criteria of the product.
x-Achsis: the criteria [0,] (0 is best)
y-Achsis: consumption probability [0,1]

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely not an elementary function. If has at least four different regimes. Unless you have an idea of the underlying physical phenomena, you can fit lots of models to that, provided you introduce enough degrees of freedom.

You'd better whatch it with a bilogarihtmic scale.